# AttributeError: module 'pythoncom' has no attribute 'Coinitialize'

Tags: win32com, python-c-api, pythoncom

My IDE is Pycharm. In order to use **win32com.client** in a new thread. I used `pythoncom.CoInitialize()` as many guys suggested here before calling `win32com.client.DispatchEx()`. But I got the following error.

```
AttributeError: module 'pythoncom' has no attribute 'Coinitialize'
```

To my understanding, this is due to that pythoncom is a C extension. How can I make the codes run well.

Comment: In the error, that capitalization in `CoInitialize` is wrong.

Comment: Hey, you are right. Thanks so much.